# Shopware 5 - Looping through all attributes

Tags: foreach, shopware

Hello i need some help with shopware.
My question is probably pretty basic but i cannot get it done. I want to print out attributes from an article. In shopware documentation they call them {$sArticle.attr1} till {$sArticle.attr20} but they can also have different names so i cannot refer directly to the name and instead i want only a few attributes to be printed.

so far i know that all attributes are stored in the s_articles_attributes database table and i only want to print out those columns when the column name containes='artikelattribut_'

The code is going to be implemented in a table from frontend/detail/tabs --> description.tpl

the actual table already uses the $sArticle.sProperties and the code looks the following:

```
{if $sArticle.sProperties}
            <div class="product--properties panel has--border">
                <table class="product--properties-table">
                    {foreach $sArticle.sProperties as $sProperty}
                        <tr class="product--properties-row">
                            {* Property label *}
                            {block name='frontend_detail_description_properties_label'}
                                <td class="product--properties-label is--bold">{$sProperty.name|escape}:</td>
                            {/block}

                            {* Property content *}
                            {block name='frontend_detail_description_properties_content'}
                                <td class="product--properties-value">{$sProperty.value|escape}</td>
                            {/block}
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}


</table>
</div>
{/if}
```

The thing is that $sArticle.sProperties and {$sArticle.attr1} till {$sArticle.attr20} are different. All i want is a second {foreach} that loops threw all article attributes maybe the idea is getting clear with that:

```
{foreach $sArticle.attr FROM s_articles_attributes WHERE name contains='artikelattribut_'}
```

I hope somebody understands my problem. Thankfull for any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind, that "properties" and "attributes" mean something different in Shopware as you might know it from other shop systems.

"Properties" are used for characteristics of a product, like the taste or colour of product.

"Attributes" in Shopware do not have anything to do with attributes in the usual meaning. You can find those `*_attributes` tables for almost every entity and they are used more like custom fields or columns which you could add to the entities to extend them with custom data.

Now back to your problem. Try this:

```
{foreach $sArticle.attributes.core->toArray() as $attributeName => $attribute}
    {$attributeName|var_dump}
    {$attribute|var_dump}
{/foreach}
```

There are two ways to access the attributes of a product.

1. All attributes are directly assigned to the `$sArticle` variable and you can use them, as you already described in your text.
2. Attributes are also stored in `$sArticle.attributes` where you can find different types of attributes. By default those are `core` and `marketing` for products on the detail page. Be aware that the values of those keys are objects of type `Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Struct\Attribute`. That's why we need to call the `toArray` method, to get an array which we can iterate.

Comment: Hello @Michael and thanks for your reply. This worked fine! 1. Do you have an idea how i would need to extend the code to only get those columns where the column name starts with 'artikelattribut_'? 2. This code: {$attribute|var_dump} gives back the content of the attribute. Any idea how i can also get the name?

Comment: hey @MaxH. 
I adjusted the example

Comment: is there a way to enter the the Label of the attribute? In Shopware Backend you find labels for the free text fields. Is there a way to get these labels instead of the names in the database? Because Labels are able to contain special characters?