# Accessing the name of a smarty variables

Tags: foreach, smarty, shopware

Hello i need some help with a basic question. This is my code:

```
{foreach $sArticle.attributes.core->toArray() as $attribute}
                        <tr class="product--properties-row">
                            <td class="product--properties-label is--bold">{$sArticle.attributes.name}{$sArticle.attributesName}</td>
                            <td class="product--properties-label is--bold">{$attribute}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}
```

1.Question: How do I enter the attributes name? I mean the column name from the attribute in the database?
2.Question: I only want to loop with the foreach through columns with name="artikelattr_" any idea how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71237355/7201069
How to get the name of the attribute.

To consider only certain attributes that starts with a specific string, just add an `if` in the loop:

```
{foreach $sArticle.attributes.core->toArray() as $attributeName => $attribute}
    {if $attributeName|strpos:"artikelattr_" === 0}
        {$attributeName|var_dump}
        {$attribute|var_dump}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

You can simply use nearly all PHP functions in Smarty.